# Trigger for filling column with values from other tables if it is empty

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I'm using sqlite3 for this database.

For an assignment I have made a database for your typical food ordering website. A table in this database called `customer_order` contains all orders placed by customers. This table also contains the columns for the delivery address of the person who ordered the food. The database also contains a table called `customer` which contains the home address of each customer (the home address of a customer is characterized by the prefix `preferred_`).

Since its possible you want food delivered to your person when you are not home, when inserting into `customer_order`, the columns that correspond to the delivery address can be some other address than the customer's home address.

What I want to do is create a trigger that automatically fills the the columns for the delivery address with the customer's home address when no delivery address is specified in the insert into the `customer_order` table.

The code I have so far is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_delivery_address BEFORE INSERT ON customer_order
WHEN address_street IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE customer_order SET address_street = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_street FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id);
    UPDATE customer_order SET address_number = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_number FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id);
    UPDATE customer_order SET address_zipcode = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_zipcode FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id);
    UPDATE customer_order SET address_city = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_city FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id);
END;
```

When I declare the database I don't get any errors, but when I try to insert into the database I get the following error:

```
Error: near line 108: no such column: address_street
```

If anyone knows how I can fix this or a better approach, any help is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_order` (
  `customer_order_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `preferred_delivery_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `address_street` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_number` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_zipcode` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_city` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `geolocation` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `is_paid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `notes` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurant(restaurant_id)
);
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `preferred_address_street` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `preferred_address_number` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `preferred_address_zipcode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `preferred_address_city` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `geolocation` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `discount_points_collected` int(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
```

Comment: You will need `After insert` trigger if i am not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is with the WHEN clause, it should be using the **new**/**old** table rather than the actual table (as it's an INSERT trigger then only **new** is avialble).

As per :-

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of
>   the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the
>   form "NEW.column-name" and "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the
>   name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.
>   OLD and NEW references may only be used in triggers on events for
>   which they are relevant, as follows:
>
> INSERT    **NEW** references are valid
>
> UPDATE    **NEW** and **OLD** references are
>   valid
>
> DELETE **OLD** references are valid

As per [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

I also believe that you'd need a WHERE clause to restrict the UPDATE's. I'd also suggest a single UPDATE rather.

As such I'd suggest using :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_delivery_address AFTER INSERT ON customer_order
WHEN new.address_street IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE customer_order SET address_street = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_street FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id),
        address_number = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_number FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id),
        address_zipcode = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_zipcode FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id),
        address_city = (SELECT customer.preferred_address_city FROM customer WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id)
    WHERE customer_order_id = new.customer_order_id;
END;
```

The above has been tested, but with only with a single new order and limited customers/users, also foreign key reference to restaurants removed, The following was used for testing:-

```
INSERT INTO customer_order VALUES(1,1,10,'2018-10-10','20:30','Fred Bloggs','1234567890','fred@fred.com',null,null,null,null,'????','0','',1);
```

The resultant row being :-

[image]

#### Alternative (simpler) Trigger using Row values :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_delivery_address 
    AFTER INSERT ON customer_order
    WHEN new.address_street IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE customer_order
        SET (address_street, address_number, address_zipcode, address_city) =
            (SELECT preferred_address_street,
                preferred_address_number,
                preferred_address_zipcode,
                preferred_address_city
            FROM customer
            WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id
        )
        WHERE customer_order_id = new.customer_order_id;
    END
;
```

**NOTE** I believe this requires at least SQLite release **3.16.1** as per (the above was tested on 3.21.0).

- > Fix a bug concerning the use of row values within triggers (see ticket
  >   8c9458e7) that was in version 3.15.0 but was not reported until
  >   moments after the 3.16.0 release was published.

---

#### SQL used for testing

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_order;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_order` (
  `customer_order_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `preferred_delivery_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `address_street` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_number` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_zipcode` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_city` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `geolocation` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `is_paid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `notes` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
  --FOREIGN KEY(restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurant(restaurant_id)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `preferred_address_street` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `preferred_address_number` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `preferred_address_zipcode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `preferred_address_city` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `geolocation` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `discount_points_collected` int(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   user_name TEXT
);
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_delivery_address;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_delivery_address 
    AFTER INSERT ON customer_order
    WHEN new.address_street IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE customer_order
        SET (address_street, address_number, address_zipcode, address_city) =
            (SELECT preferred_address_street,
                 preferred_address_number,
                preferred_address_zipcode,
                        preferred_address_city
                FROM customer
            WHERE customer.user_id = customer_order.user_id
        )
        WHERE customer_order_id = new.customer_order_id;
    END
;
INSERT INTO user (user_name) VALUES ('Fred'),('Bert'),('Harry'),('Tom');
INSERT INTO customer (
                user_id,
                preferred_address_street,
                preferred_address_number,
                preferred_address_zipcode,
                preferred_address_city,
                geolocation,discount_points_collected)
    VALUES (1,'Somerset Blvd','1','12345','Syndey','?????',100);
INSERT INTO customer_order (
                 customer_order_id,
                 user_id,
                 restaurant_id,
                 preferred_delivery_time,
                 full_name,
                 phone_number,
                 email_address,
                 geolocation,
                 is_paid,
                 notes
            )
    VALUES(1,1,20,'21:30','Fred Bloggs','0000 000 000','Fred@Bloggs.com','x',0,'not to note');
```

Comment: In SQLite 3.15 or later, the update can be made simpler with [row values](http://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html#row_values_in_update_statements).

Comment: @CL.I tried this on DB Browser, with 3.15.2 it kept on crashing. I think it needs at least 3.16.1. Tried with SQLite Manager with 3.21.0 and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Update every column separately using insert join for trigger. You will need `after insert` trigger

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_delivery_address ON customer_order
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE c
    SET address_street = cu.preferred_address_street
    FROM customer_order c
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON c.user_id = i.user_id
    INNER JOIN Customer cu ON c.user_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE c.Address_street IS NULL

    UPDATE c
    SET address_number = cu.preferred_address_number
    FROM customer_order c
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON c.user_id = i.user_id
    INNER JOIN Customer cu ON c.user_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE c.Address_street IS NULL

    UPDATE c
    SET address_zipcode = cu.preferred_address_zipcode
    FROM customer_order c
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON c.user_id = i.user_id
    INNER JOIN Customer cu ON c.user_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE c.Address_street IS NULL

    UPDATE c
    SET address_city = cu.preferred_address_city
    FROM customer_order c
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON c.user_id = i.user_id
    INNER JOIN Customer cu ON c.user_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE c.Address_street IS NULL
END;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `INSERTED i` if I may ask. Becuase the code you provided sadly didnt work. I still get the same error

Comment: @Okkibro you must be inserting customer id into customer_order table when they order